# Perform a facet search query with Algolia autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, algolia, faceted-search

My index objects has a `city` field and I'd like to retrieve these with autocomplete, but documentation seems missing about how to perform a query (only basic search documentation is available), I found a prototype `IndexCore.prototype.searchForFacetValues` in the `autocomplete.js` but I have no idea to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following source:

```js
var client = algoliasearch("YourApplicationID", "YourSearchOnlyAPIKey");
var index = client.initIndex("YourIndex");

autocomplete("#search-input", { hint: false }, [
  {
    source: function(query, callback) {
      index
        .searchForFacetValues({
          facetName: "countries",
          facetQuery: query
        })
        .then(function(answer) {
          callback(answer.hits);
        })
        .catch(function() {
          callback([]);
        });
    },
    displayKey: "my_attribute",
    templates: {
      suggestion: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion._highlightResult.my_attribute.value;
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

This uses the `searchForFacetValues` method to get the results.

Comment: Strangely, it throws a `400 bad request` with `Cannot search in city attribute, you need to add searchable(city) to attributesForFaceting.` while I already configure it as searchable.

Comment: Are you sure you added it in that index? I think that’s the only reason that error can be thrown. Can you send an email to support@algolia.com if you can’t get it to work?

Comment: Sorry, I missed something in the config, thanks for the answer.